# SQL same space between 2 format of 1 field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I'm using MS SQL, and my query is like this:

```
select
A.CUS_EuroCustId No_Id, 
' '  BLANK1,
A.IVC_Number INV_Nr , 
'     ' BLANK2, 
'PINV' PINV ,  
' ' BLANK3,

from 
INVOICE as A
```

Then the output is like this:

```
  01102450 146918     PINV 
  01102847 146381     PINV 
  01105915 16151     PINV 
  01102646 146850     PINV
  01105915 16150     PINV
```

The IVC_Number has two format, 6 digits and 5 digits and the space between IVC_Number and 'PINV' is important. Now how can I make it in my SQL query and the output should be like this:

```
  01102450 146918     PINV 
  01102847 146381     PINV 
  01105915 16151      PINV 
  01102646 146850     PINV
  01105915 16150      PINV
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you doing this in SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`LEFT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) and add some padding yourself:

```
LEFT(A.IVC_Number+'    ',6) INV_Nr ,
```

And it will always be 6 characters wide.

---

Although, of course, in the current query, each column should be being displayed separately anyway - something is combining all of the columns together into a single piece of text, and I'd usually recommend pushing string formatting out to whatever that component is, rather than working in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative -- you'll need to be using a monotype (fixed-width) font to see the results, but the spacing should be correct (adjust accordingly -- both are currently set to 7 chars):

```
SELECT 
   RIGHT('       ' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(7)), 7) + 
   RIGHT('       ' + CAST(INV_Nr  AS VARCHAR(7)), 7) +
   PINV
FROM Test
```

And the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/43db6/5).

Good luck.